# MySQL ignores index on binary column

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with binary column indexed. Observe very slow queries with *where binary_column = x'....'* condition on MySQL 5.0.45

Created test table like

```
CREATE TABLE  `test` (
  `h` binary(20) NOT NULL,
  `a` int(10) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`h`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Then running test query after each of several inserts of 10k rows

```
SELECT count(a) FROM test where binary h = x'...';
or
SELECT count(a) FROM test where binary h = unhex('...');
```

Observe linear increase of time spent for these queries with number of rows growing. Index is created (primary key!): I see 1Mb of data file and 1.5Mb index file.
Explain command confirms primary key is not used:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys key   key_len ref   rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE      test    ALL     null          null  null    null  40014 Using where
```

How to make MySQL to use index for binary column?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `binary` operator?  This is probably preventing use of the index.

Comment: Explain shows the same ignorance of keys and Extra = Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables

Comment: Seems that it's old bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15907 But is there any workaround except base38 encoding of binary field into char?

Comment: Any updates regarding the issue?